# How could i make a command to send a specific message to a specific person?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Just saying already I'm pretty new to programming but after trying to read the documentation for a few hours I gave up.

I'm trying to create a command that goes like `!dm "User" "Message content"` but I can't make it to work, I have found three problems that are making me go crazy.

I don't know how to separate two arguments, I don't know how to specify the user to send and I don't know how to get the user ID from the argument.

This is my command:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');


module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const A = args.join(' ')
    message.author = args.join(message.mentions.members);
    message.author.send(A)

}
```

But as you guys can see I don't know what I'm doing, I hope you guys can help me.

I want to send the message in the dm.

Comment: please remove the "that are making me go crazy." part, which is completely irrelevant to the question. the goal of stackoverflow is to provide the whole community with answers. discussing personal feelings stays in the way.

Comment: try to reformulate the question. I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your command handler, I'm assuming the way you get your args is by doing
`args.split(" ")`

This will work in most cases but like here, when you need spaces in the arguments it gets very fiddly.

I suggest using the code I have placed underneath to get your command word and args

```js
// make sure whatever your prefix is, is already defined
const prefix = "!"

const input = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim();
const args = [];
input.match(/"[^"]+"|[\S]+/g).forEach((element) => {
    if (!element) return null;
    return args.push(element.replace(/"/g, ''));
});
console.log(args);

// get the command keyword (first word after prefix)
let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();


const command = client.commands.get(cmd); // get the command from the name however you stored it
command.run(client, message, args) // run the command
```

Then in your command you can just do

```js
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    // get either the user from the first mention or from a given userId
    let userToSendTo = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])

    // args[1] contains the entire message because of the argument parsing code I gave you (above)
    userToSendTo.send(args[1])

}
```

All the code above relies on the user writing in the format

!dm @user "message that has spaces in is wrapped with quotation marks"